# Swift - GeoFire removeObserver Not Working, seeking for workaround please

Tags: ios, swift, geofire, geofirestore

I find out that both removeObserver and .removeAllObservers() is not working in GeoFire, hoping another work around to "get out" of this observe (which keeps loading forever)

```
var newRefHandle: FIRDatabaseHandle?
var gFCircleQuery: GFCircleQuery?

func findFUsersInOnePath(location: CLLocation,
                         radius: Int,
                         indexPath: String,
                         completion: @escaping () -> ()){
    var ids = 0
    let geofireRef = usersRef.child(indexPath)
    if let geoFire = GeoFire(firebaseRef: geofireRef) {
        gFCircleQuery = geoFire.query(at: location, withRadius: Double(radius))
        newRefHandle = gFCircleQuery?.observe(.keyEntered, with: { (key, location) in
            // if key fit some condition then perform some other firebase call to other database(async), afterwards:
            ids += 1
            if (ids >= 3) {
                //RemoveObersver not working below...
                self.gFCircleQuery?.removeObserver(withFirebaseHandle: self.newRefHandle!)
                completion()
            }
        })
        //I find that observeReady gets call right away despite we haven't complete  code above 
        gFCircleQuery?.observeReady({
            completion()
        })
}
```

Comment: "not working" is really hard to help with. What data are you querying, what is the behavior you see (showing it with just logging statement typically helps a lot to ensure we're on the same page), and what did you expect to see?

Comment: I expect the observer to "detach" and remove from "observing", but it did nothing, hence I called it "not working".

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you're still getting some `.keyEntered` events after the call to `removeObserver`, which is actually to be expected.

GeoFire performs a single query to get all keys within the range for your query, and then calls your `.keyEntered` callback for each of these keys. Even if you call `removeObserver` for the first key, GeoFire will continue to call the `.keyEntered` callback with the remainder of the keys that it already got from the database.

For this reason, I'd recommend removing the observer inside the [ready block](https://github.com/firebase/geofire-objc/#waiting-for-queries-to-be-ready) for the query. The behavior will not change when you do that, but it'll make more sense as that ready block is called when GeoFire is done telling you about the batch of keys.

Comment: I have also tried to remove the Observer in ready block but it did not work...

Comment: "it did not work" is not really easy to help with. What happened? What did you expect to happen? Can you add logging code (and its output) to show that problem?

Comment: I expect the observer to "detach" and remove from "observing", but it did nothing, hence I called it "not working".

Comment: I'm really trying to help Ryan, but I just don't have enough information. Unless you can provide the information I asked for, there is not much more I can do for you.

Comment: Expected: when call removeObserver, it will remove KeyEntered event called. What happen is when called this function (even inside the ready block), it did NOT remove KeyEntered event. Is there any additional information required?

Comment: add logging code and print outputs would help